# Set Theory in terms of $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$ question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given 3 sets, $X=\{0,1,2,3\}, Y=\{0,3,4,5\}$ and $Z=\{0,1,5,6\}$. I am then asked to give the set $\{0,5\}$ and $\{0,1,2,3,5\}$ in terms of $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$ and $X,Y,Z$.

I have answers for both but I feel as if I am missing something out. For the first I have written  $Y\bigcap Z$ and for the second $Y\bigcap Z \bigcup X$. I drew a venn diagram for the first and saw $\{0,5\}$ existed in both $X$ and $Z$ but 0 also existed in $Z$, is my thinking wrong?

Comment: You need to be careful where you put your brackets. The set $(Y \cap Z) \cup X$ is not the same as $Y \cap (Z \cup X)$, so writing $Y \cap Z \cup X$ is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Y \cap Z = \{ 0 , 5\}$$

$$(Y \cap Z) \cup X = \{ 0, 5\} \cup \{0,1,2,3\}=\{0,1,2,3,5\}$$

$\{0,5\}$ appears in both $X$ and $Z$? I don't see $5$ in $X$. $\{0,5\}$ is a subset of $Y \cap Z$ and in fact they are equal.

Comment: I see, that makes much more sense.